# Symfony2.8 - doctrine:schema:update - Nothing to update after adding new field

Tags: doctrine-orm

I have added new field

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="date", unique=false, nullable=true)
 */
private $last_status_change;
```

To entity

```
/**
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\TestRepository")
* @ORM\Table(name="entity_test")
*/
class Test
```

and generated setters, getters. Now when I run command doctrine:schema:update it tells me "Nothing to update - your database is already in sync with the current entity metadata."

Okay well then I have tried "rm -rf ./app/cache/*" and then running command "doctrine:cache:clear-metadata" well it tells me "Clearing ALL Metadata cache entries - No cache entries were deleted."

When I try to remove field to test if doctrine can find changes in entity, then it throws error that a given field is missing.

So makes no sense that it does not detect new field.

This is a big application with 30+ entities and not my first symfony project, so I am surprised that this never happened to me before.

Any ideas?

PS.: schema:validate also returns that everything is all right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of debuging problem solved by simply restarting memcached service...